Putting up shelves in an older mobile home
I have a 20-year-old double wide. I don't know if the studs are wood or metal. I'd like to have shelves, preferably floating, installed on a wall in my office. I want the shelves to hold a couple of books, knick-knacks, framed pictures and maybe a small plant. Is this possible?

What is your wall finish? Paneling or drywall? A picture will help.

The guidelines for manufactured homes have become much more stringent over the years. In 1994 the rules got even stricter to require the homes to comply to the same building codes for permanent structures.  I mention this because your home should be built with the same type of construction as required for any home of the same period (2000s)
You should have 2x4 walls which can support a good amount of weight if anchors are attached to them properly.
If you cannot find the "studs" in your walls,There are tools you can purchase to help find them. multi sensor types work well for me.   If you are not handy and somewhat familiar with how the home was built, hire a handyman to install the shelves.
Having a mobile or manufactured home in the the 20 year old range does not eliminate having things like floating shelves.
